# Fields in which $ -1 $ can't be written as sum of two square elements

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory, number-fields

We say a field $F$ has the property $*$ if the equation $x^2 + y^2=-1$ has no solution in $F$. For an example if $F$ is a subfield of real numbers then $F$ satisfies $*$. On the other hand if $ F $ is a finite field then by Chevalley-Warning theorem the equation $ x^2 + y^2 =-1 $  always has a solution.
I want to know which fields that satisfy property $ * $. Does this type of field belong to a special class of field?

Comment: For what it's worth, these are precisely the fields over which the quaternion group $Q_8$ has a four dimensional irreducible representation. You might also want to look up the theory of Severi-Brauer varieties.

Comment: "Additionally, it is assumed": you don't need this assumption, which is an immediate consequence of the definition.

Comment: Yes we don't need this assumption. I have edited.

Comment: There are many such fields with rather disparate properties, and I don’t think there is any kind of classification. FWIW, these are called the fields of [Stufe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_(algebra)) 2.

Comment: I mean, of Stufe more than $2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the notation of Lam's *Quadratic forms over fields*, the *Stufe* (a German word) or *level* (its English translation) $s(F)$ of a field is the minimal $n$ such that $-1$ is the sum of $n$ squares.

A theorem of Pfister says that $s(F)$ is always a power of $2$ (or $\infty$).

So you are taking of fields $F$ such that $s(F) > 2$ (or $s(F) \geq 4$, if you are willing to use Pfister's theorem).

Comment: Why would you be not willing to use Pfister's theorem? In this special case, it is an immediate consequence of the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), hence it is has a short, completely elementary proof.

Comment: What will be the stuff for padic field?